# How can i get points from a 3D Surface (plot_surface())

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, surface, plot3d

Well, the problem I have is the following one.

I have data for axis X, Y and Z, and I want to plot the surface. For that I first interpolate/extrapolate to get , more mesh points and then I plot the surface (in Python) with plot_surface() function and I get it.
Later I have to use those points that I have for the mesh (already interpolated) as input in another function. As output I want the new surface and get it. But how can I get the coordinates of every point of that surface? As if I pointed with the cursor at that point.

I have to interpolate again?
Or there is other way?

Comment: What is "every point"? That would be an infinite number of points.

Comment: I mean given a random valure to X and Y in the right range, to get Z values

Comment: Still an infinite number of points between [0,0,z1] and [0, 1, z2] unless you define a step (say, 0.01), in which case you can interpolate your z-value.